# How much can I safely plug into a light socket converted to a standard outlet?

Tags: safety, low-power, light

I just moved my office desk from our extra bedroom on to our stairway landing.  The tricky thing was that there was no wall outlet to plug anything into.  However, there was a nearby light socket, which I converted into a standard outlet using a [GE polarized handy outlet](http://www.walmart.com/ip/GE-Polarized-Handy-Outlet-Brown-2pk/16644761#Specifications). 
Upon reading the label on the packaging, it says there is a 125VAC 660W max.  It also said on the back to not exceed electrical ratings in order to avoid the risk of fire.  I also had to use a [Non-grounded to grounded plug converter](http://www.walmart.com/ip/GE-Non-Grounded-to-Grounded-Plug-Adapter-Gray-2pk/16644747) to be able to plug my power strip in.

I'm not an electrician and I don't know too much about this beyond my high school electronics class.  Am I going to be safe if the only things I have plugged in to it are my Macbook Pro and my flatscreen LED LCD monitor?  I have done some research for my macbook to see how much power it uses and found that it rarely will ever go above 45 watts.  Assuming my LCD monitor also doesn't exceed much more than that it seems to reason that I would be safe.  ~100 watts is far less than the 660 watt limit. Am I making some correct assumptions here?  What else do I need to consider?  Would I also be safe to plug in a printer and possibly more appliances?

Comment: I'd say this is off topic here, but would be well served at http://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This all around sounds like a bad idea.  You can use up to 660 W or whatever the lamp socket was rated for *whichever is less*.  Also, the ground cheater adapter is a just plain bad idea.

Comment: This question is off-topic but it's preserved because it's already been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And I am concerned about the poor light socket.  Most standard light sockets say something like

> 100W max

This refers to the lamp that you can safely use in that socket. The main variable that goes into that calculation, I believe, is the heat dissipation: most of the energy produced by an incandescent light bulb is in the form of heat, and the lamp fixture+socket has to be able to withstand the heat put out by the bulb.

However, there are other factors, namely, the current rating the wires leading to the light socket and the electrical connections inside the socket itself. If the wires and connections are safe for under 1 Amp, then you can't use a larger than 100W bulb (given 120V AC). In the end you cannot know what part which factors play in the power rating of the socket, and so I would advise to find out the power rating of the light socket itself, and not exceed that either.

Bottom line: the "Handy Hutlet" might allow 660W, but the light socket is unlikely to, and you'd be wise not to exceed the power rating of the weakest link in the chain.

Comment: While it's true that a table lamp might have only an AWG18 or AWG16 line cord, any permanently-wired lamp socket will probably have AWG14 right up to the socket. In the US, the NEC requires it, because of the type of potential usage described by the OP.

Answer (score 5):

> Am I going to be safe if the only things I have plugged in to it are my Macbook Pro and my flatscreen LED LCD monitor?

No, you will not be absolutely safe. You might be relatively safe, though, and the risk might be worth it to you.

The issue is not the current capability of the light socket, though, it is the lack of a proper ground.  Your computer and monitor both have grounded plugs for your safety.  They are internally isolated to a significant degree, but it is possible for them to fail in a way that might place an unacceptably high voltage on their surface or controls in a place you could touch.  Even if they are working properly, they might carry a charge relative to the place you are at in the home.

I've had situations where a computer was at 90V potential compared to the concrete floor I was standing on because it was running on a long extension cord with a missing ground pin.

Your situation isn't much different, which means there's a potential for a shock hazard.

> I have done some research for my macbook to see how much power it uses and found that it rarely will ever go above 45 watts. Assuming my LCD monitor also doesn't exceed much more than that it seems to reason that I would be safe. ~100 watts is far less than the 660 watt limit. Am I making some correct assumptions here?

If your house has standard electrical circuit breakers, it is likely that this circuit will handle 15A of current, but you need to take into account all the other lights and devices connected to the same circuit.

The lamp socket itself may support up to 15 amps, but it's likely to be lower.  I'd feel safe drawing 5-10 amps from most light sockets that still have shiny brass at the bottom, and less if it's dull or corroded.

Your computer and monitor are fine, but I'd avoid attaching much else unless it's also under 100-200W.

However, it's not difficult to replace a light fixture with an electrical outlet, and the light fixture can be put back in place later without any visible changes.

Even better, replace the light fixture with one that has a built-in outlet:

[image: Image of generic light fixture with a typical US style outlet on one side]

[http://www.amazon.com/Leviton-9726-C-One-Piece-Incandescent-Lampholder/dp/B00002N5FR](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00002N5FR)

This won't work if your home is very, very old and might not have grounded wires coming to the light fixture, but chances are good it has the normal grounded wire, and all you need is a screwdriver to take the old one out and put this one, or a similar one, in.  Make certain that the circuit breaker is off before doing this, though.

Going this route is the best - you don't have to worry about how much current the socket can carry, since you'll be using an outlet that can carry 15 amps.  You can inspect the wiring and understand which breaker you're on, which will tell you how much current the circuit can carry.  You'll have to turn the circuit off, so you'll know what other lights and outlets are on this same circuit (go around and test). You'll still be left with a light at the stair landing (which is required by many building codes) and you'll have a grounded, three prong outlet which will resolve your grounding issue.